# Vertical Timeline CSS / Jquery With expanding content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am really stuck in this.

I am developing a vertical timeline just like facebook. But the layout is different because the content are expandable and the bullets must not overlap each other. Also the list item must have equal margins and distances.

I have already tried to apply the style from this [site](http://htun.me/labs/timeline.php) because all the items have the same margins(spacing) and I found out that  it's not applicable in my case, because when you expand the item using that style, those bullets will overlap each other, they must move downward.

I am planning to achieve this by using jquery, but I don't know how to compute formulas for margin. Can somebody help me achieve the solution for my problem? Thanks.

Thanks.

Comment: Demo link here http://jsfiddle.net/6CCT7/

Comment: This is what I want to achieve http://prntscr.com/2rhmsg (equal margins / spacings) , This is what my code generates http://prntscr.com/2rhmu6